# Capturing a button click as part of a field validation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

I have an `onblur='validate(this)'` on a text field but I do not want the validate code to run when a cancel button is clicked.

```js
function validate(oField) {
    if (document.getElementById('Cancel').clicked != true) {
        console.log("Cancel clicked");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id='reviewername' 
       name='reviewername' 
       type='text' 
       class='$class' 
       value='$reviewername' 
       tabindex=1 
       size=$size 
       onkeydown='setKeyCode(event)' 
       onblur='validate(this)'/>;

<input type='submit' 
       name='Button' 
       id='Cancel' 
       value='Cancel'>;
```

The `document.getElementById('Cancel').clicked` is always 'undefined'.
I have tried `addListener()`, probably incorrectly, as well as other newbie tricks with no success!

What I am trying to do is check whether the Cancel button is clicked while the text field has the focus. Immediately I click the button, the text field event `'onblur'` runs. I want to check for the button click as the first part of the javascript `validate()` function.

Is what I am attempting even possible?

Please help before I lose the rest of my hair.

Comment: `clicked` is not a valid property on a HTML element. What're you trying to do here? If you want to check if the button has been clicked before, you will need to store that state somewhere, which is updated when the button is clicked on.

Comment: @Terry - What I am trying to do is check whether the Cancel button is clicked while the text field has the focus.  Immediately I click the button, the text field 'onblur' runs.  I want to check for the button click as the first part of the javascript validate().

Answer (score 0):

You ***can*** use `àddListener()` if you name it correctly as `addEventListener()`.
Then, you can set some variable when the cancel button is clicked and use that variable in replacement to your `document.getElementById(...).clicked`.

```js
cancel_clicked = false;

function validate(oField) {
    if (cancel_clicked != true) {
        console.log("Cancel not clicked");
    } else {
        console.log("Cancel clicked");
    }
}
```

```html
<input id='reviewername' 
       name='reviewername' 
       type='text' 
       class='$class' 
       value='$reviewername' 
       tabindex=1 
       size=$size 
       onkeydown='setKeyCode(event);' 
       onblur='validate(this);'/>

<input type='submit' 
       name='Button' 
       id='Cancel' 
       value='Cancel'
       onclick='cancel_clicked = true;'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are removing direct event listener attachment to DOM elements, it's better to use javascript to add the event listeners, instead of the onlick or onblur attributes on DOM elements, this is what I've noticed lately.. So you are more safe with using addEventListener, also do watch out for your spelling too incases where you get undefined,or you are loading your script before your DOM tree.. As a thumb rule, load your javascript file last.